# Server side or client side data manipulation

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-4.0, ria

I'm working on a silverlight business application at work and I'm wondering what should I be doing in the following scenario :

There's a xaml page which is the main point of working in the application and it uses SQL in the backend to bring data from many tabels and bind it using some logic in 5 different datagrids.

In the front end , there are few data converters which are doing some operation based on the values they get .

It would be better(performance) to move all the 'data converters' logic in the server side or I should be sticking with the converters?

Comment: Why are you considering to move the logic to server?. Have you detected performance problems?. Having the logic at client side is much more scalable, because clients are many and there is only one server. I'm very confident converters are not a performance botleneck. If there are performance problems look at other places.

Comment: I thought this may cause performance issues so I considered to move the logic to the server so I can have a the logic the entire logic in a single place. But given your answer , It would be better not doing that.